# C language: recursive #include

Tags: c, programming-languages

I came across such piece of code:

a.h:

```
#include "b.h"
/* structure definitions, macros etc. */
```

b.h:

```
    #include "a.h"
/* structure definitions, macros etc. */
```

Is this legal from the C standard point of view? I would think such approach isn't safe.

Comment: C has a lot of legal things which should not be legal. :D     "ifndef" should have been used as many responders are saying.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). Then it will be safe.

```
a.h
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
/* ... */

#endif
```

Answer (score 6):

It is legal.  All compilers that I know of impose a nesting limit, usually in the range of 20 to 50.  Recursion, if useful, is easily controlled with condtionals:

```
#if NESTING < 5
 #define NESTING NESTING+1
 #include "myself.h"
#endif
```

There are thousands of ways to shoot yourself in the foot as a programmer.  This is just one more way.  Be careful.

Answer (score 3):

That's where [**`include guards`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) come handy.

Answer (score 1):

It's legal. But it's not guaranteed to result in anything useful. Use forward declarations and include guards to get rid of such circular dependencies.